# Can I default class member functions and specify extra specifiers?

Tags: c++

I have a problem where if I use my class as the element type in a vector it doesn't move it but rather constructs it and tries to copy assign it (I believe because the compiler sees certain functions as throwing exceptions). I don't want to redefine my own move constructor every time this happens, can I default the move constructor but specify that it's noexcept?

```
struct QueueSubmission
{
    QueueSubmission(VulkanFence is_completed_fence) : is_completed_fence(is_completed_fence)
    {}
    QueueSubmission(QueueSubmission&& other) noexcept = default; 
    QueueSubmission& operator=(QueueSubmission&& other) noexcept = default;
/* CommandBufferUniquePointer cannot be copied, but only moved */   
std::vector<CommandBufferUniquePointer> command_buffers_submitted;

};
```

Comment: If the implicit move operations weren't `noexcept` automatically, then this means that one of the member's move operations isn't `noexcept`. It would be preferable to fix the exception specification of the members, otherwise you risk a program abort if an exception still makes it through. In your shown code the implicit move operations should be `noexcept`, because `std::vector` is noexcept-movable.  (at least since C++17, but probably also before that)

Comment: Just to clarify: "_use my class as the element type in a vector_" refers to `QueueSubmission` or `CommandBufferUniquePointer`?

Comment: You can also `delete` the copy constructor. And note the rule of five: of you specify one of the special functions, you need to do it for all five. But if you leave it default, like you seem to do, you could still use the rule of zero and specify none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if functions are defaulted on their first declaration without `noexcept` specifier, then they will be `noexcept(true)` if and only if they don't contain anything potentially throwing.

But if you add a `noexcept` specifier this will override it.

Note my comments under your question though.